# Overriding specific third party Woocommerce plugin templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, subscriptions

I'm using a Woocommerce based plugin called [Mix 'n Match Products](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/).

This plugin sits inside `/plugins/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/`
This folder contains another folder for templates.

Following convention, I have copied the "**templates**" folder into my child theme and changed the folder name to "**woocommerce-mix-and-match-products**"

The structure is now `themes/storevilla-child/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/`

However, none of the templates override the plugin templates. I have tested. Only once I change the actual plugin template files, does the HTML change.

Can anybody spot what I may be doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to do it is a little bit different. All WooThemes woocommerce plugins use the default woocommerce templates folder described in [**this documentation**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/):

**2 cases:**

1. You have already a **`woocommerce`** folder in your active child theme (or theme). 
   Copy from `plugins/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/templates/single-product/mnm/` 
   to `themes/your_active_theme/woocommerce/single-product/` 
   And  `plugins/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/mnm.php` 
   inside `themes/your_active_theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/`
2. You don't have any **`woocommerce`** folder in your active child theme (or theme). 
   Copy from `plugins/woocommerce-mix-and-match-products/templates/` 
   inside your active child theme (or theme) and rename it **`woocommerce`**.

> So in your case you will have: **`themes/storevilla-child/woocommerce/`**

Reference: [WooCommerce Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)

Comment: Great. Thank you. That's where I went wrong. @LoicTheAztec