# Custom templates in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to make a separate template for only one product with ID 5555. To delete a photo from its page and change the blocks structure. Overriding this file affects all product pages.

```
wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\content-single-product.php
```

The logical solution is to add a condition: if the product single prpduct page have ID 5555, then another template is used for its page.
I tried this option, but it does not work.

```
/**
 * Custom single product template.
 */

add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' );
function get_custom_post_type_template($single_template) {
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type == 'product') {
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-template.php';
    }
    return $single_template;
}

add_filter( 'template_include', 'portfolio_page_template', 99 );
function portfolio_page_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_page( 'slug' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'single-template.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Or option 2: remove this hooks:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );
```

from only one specific product page:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> #### Custom templates specifically since Woocommerce 3.3
>
> **Since Woocommerce 3.3 Wordpress hook `template_include` doesn't seem to work always**, as you could see in a lot of recent related threads in StackOverFlow and somewhere else too.
>
> ---
>
> **The specific filter hooks related to templates for Woocommerce:**
>
> - [**`wc_get_template`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_template.html#207)
> - [**`wc_get_template_part`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_template_part.html#177)
> - [`woocommerce_locate_template`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_locate_template.html#272)
> - [`woocommerce_template_path`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WooCommerce.html#581) *(The theme's override templates folder)*

---

#### Case 1. Using `wc_get_template_part` *(your case)*:

If you look at `single-product.php` template, the `content-single-product.php` template is loaded with the following at this line:

```
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>
```

So we will use the hook [`wc_get_template_part`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_template_part.html#177).

Let say that **your custom template replacement file** is named `content-single-product-custom.php` and located in the `woocommerce` folder of your active child theme (or active theme). To use this custom template for a **specific product ID** *(`5555`)* you will need the following:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template_part', 'custom_wc_template_part', 10, 3 );
function custom_wc_template_part( $template, $slug, $name ) {
    // The specific product ID
    $product_id = 5555; 

    // The custom template file name
    $custom_template_name = 'content-single-product-custom.php'; 

    // For a specific product ID and content-single-product.php template
    if( get_the_ID() == $product_id && $slug == 'content' && $name == 'single-product' ){
        $template = trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . 'woocommerce/' . $custom_template_name;
    }
    return $template;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### Case 2. Using `wc_get_template`:

If templates is loaded via [`wc_get_template()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_template.html#184-214) function, like for example `single-product/meta.php` and your custom replacement template is named `single-product/custom-meta.php` *(and located in the woocommerce folder of your active child theme)*. To use this custom template for a **specific product ID** *(`5555`)* you will need the following:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'custom_wc_template', 10, 5 );
function custom_wc_template( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {
    // The specific product ID
    $product_id = 5555;

    // The custom template file name and path
    $custom_template_name = 'single-product/custom-meta.php';

    if( is_product() && get_the_ID() == 37 && $template_name == 'single-product/meta.php'){
        $located = trailingslashit( get_stylesheet_directory() ) . 'woocommerce/' . $custom_template_name;
    }
    return $located;
}
```

This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

#### About overriding woocommerce templates:

- Official documentation: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)
- [Overriding specific third party Woocommerce plugin templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568208/overriding-specific-third-party-woocommerce-plugin-templates/39570412#39570412)

Comment: Thank you very much, Loic! I checked the code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your theme's 'functions.php' where **5** is product ID and **woocommerce/single-product-watermelon.php** is custom product template.

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'watermelon_template_include' );

function watermelon_template_include( $template ) {
    if ( is_singular('product') && get_the_ID() == 5 ) { //if category, change has_term( 'watermelon', 'product_cat') instead of get_the_ID()
        $template = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/woocommerce/single-product-watermelon.php';
    } 
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: There are no changes unfortunately... 5 - product id?

Comment: Yes 5 is product ID.

Comment: First, add some characters to `woocommerce/single-product-watermelon.php` and confirm whether it's loading for product ID 5. Please note that WooCommerce hooks will work same as normal product template and it's better to apply your customizations directly without using WooCommerce hooks.